How to access the access token into child components from the parent component using BehaviourSubject, when they are rendered using router-outlet?
login.component.ts -> Child component
public onSubmit(formData: object): void {
    this.userService.setLoggedInUser(formData as LoggedInUsers);
    this.userService.getAccessToken().subscribe((accessToken: AccessToken) => {
      if(accessToken && accessToken.token) {
        this.router.navigate(['/todo-list']);
      } else {
        this.toastrService.error('Invalid credentials, sign up to create an account');
      }
    });    
  }

app.component.ts -> Parent component
public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.usersService.getLoggedInUser().pipe(map((user: LoggedInUsers) => {
      return this.usersService.validateUser(user).subscribe((accessToken: AccessToken) => {
        if(accessToken) {
          this.token = accessToken;          
          this.usersService.setAccessToken(this.token);
        }        
      });
    }));
  }

user.service.ts -> Global shareable service
@Injectable({
    'providedIn': 'root'
})
export class UsersService {
    isAuthenticated$: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
    authenticatedUser$: BehaviorSubject<LoggedInUsers> = new BehaviorSubject<LoggedInUsers>(null);    
    accessToken$: BehaviorSubject<AccessToken> = new BehaviorSubject<AccessToken>(null);
    constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

    postUser(user: RegisteredUsers): Observable<number[]> {      
        return this.http.post<number[]>(ApiConstants.postUser(), user, {
            headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        });
    }

    validateUser(user: LoggedInUsers): Observable<AccessToken> {
        return this.http.post<AccessToken>(ApiConstants.postLoggedUser(), user, {
            headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type','application/json')
        }).pipe(tap((response: AccessToken) => {               
                this.isAuthenticated$.next(true);                                
                this.accessToken$.next(response);                
        }));
    }

    getLoggedInUser(): Observable<LoggedInUsers> {
        return this.authenticatedUser$.asObservable();
    }

    setLoggedInUser(user: LoggedInUsers): void {
        this.authenticatedUser$.next(user);
    }
    
    setAccessToken(token: AccessToken): void {
        this.accessToken$.next(token);
    }

    getAccessToken(): Observable<AccessToken> {
        return this.accessToken$.asObservable();
    }
}

I want to store the access token at the global location from where I can easily give the access to the access token and if app reloads, then the app state is retained. I'll use the NgXS state management and browser storage concept here in the future, but for now I'm starting from the basics and I want to play around it.
